# How do I prevent GNU Screen from reseting my prompt?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

When I run screen it changes my prompt.  How do I prevent this behaviour?  For example:

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\h:Prod\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
$ screen
$ echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

Interestingly, it does not do this on other machines.  The machine in question is Redhat 4 update 4, with Screen version 4.00.02 (FAU) 5-Dec-03.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding (assuming it's not already there) to your .screenrc file:

```
shell -$SHELL
```

This will give you a login shell when you initialize a screen session or create another terminal from within one.

Comment: I had 'shell /bin/bash' in my .screenrc, apparently it should have been 'shell -/bin/bash' or what you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Many distributions check the type of terminal before setting the prompt.  Ubuntu, for example, contains this little gem in the default .bashrc:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

Since screen uses its own TERM variable ("screen"), bash thinks it's not capable of displaying a fancy color prompt so it defaults to a simpler one.  Screen is, of course, fully capable of the same complex prompts as a normal terminal.

So, to override this behavior, just hard-set your preferred PS1 options at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.  Or, if you're feeling adventurous, find the test that checks the value of the TERM variable and modify it to accept "screen" in addition to "xterm-color".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a customized variable that is set in the ~/.screenrc file?

Comment: Yes, check for setenv PS1 in global or personal screenrc

Comment: And what customized variable would that be?  If you don't know the answer, don't answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (no more custom prompt in screen) on a machine with
`SHELL -$SHELL` and no `setenv PS1` in screenrc, and no special test for (dumb) terminal in bashrc.

Setting the used $TERM:

```
$ echo $TERM
urxvt-unicode-256color
```

in screenrc got my custom prompt back while under Screen:

```
- #term xterm-256color
+ term urxvt-unicode-256color
```

PS: another account had no need for this, but bashrc tests for dircolors and a modern terminal this way[1](http://www.archlinux.org):

```
if [[ $'\n'${match_lhs} == *$'\n'"TERM "${safe_term}* ]] ; then
PS1=<my fancy prompt>
```

I believe this works as well:

```
if [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ]; then
PS1=<my fancy prompt>
```